# Calculate total from number input and set to number input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Helo, I have some problems on my calculate script, why I can not calculate example: 23+20*2=86 when I calculate he gather + and not * why ? hre is the script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('div#cont-sum-fields').on('change', 'input', function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('#cont-sum-fields').find('input[id^="cont-sum"]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() !== "") total += parseFloat($(this).val())
        });
        $('#cont-sum-fields').find('#total-cont-sum').val(total);
    });
});//]]>  
</script>


<body>
  <div id='cont-sum-fields'>
    <input type="number" id="cont-sum-1" /> 
    <input type="number" id="cont-sum-2" /> 
    <input type="number" id="cont-sum-3" /> 
    <input id="total-cont-sum" type="number" disabled />
  </div>
</body>
```

where I wrong?

Comment: All we can say is that your code does what it says. What do you want to get?

Comment: you have no `*` at all in your code, so why should javascript multiply anything for you?  perhaps you want `total *= parseFloat(...)`?

Comment: How do you want this script to work. Currently it just adds the values from all fields.

Comment: I want to calculate example  23+20*2=86

Comment: and now he calculated like example:  23+20+2=45 I do not want this

Comment: you have summation not multiplication, your code is not too smart to guess what you want

Comment: then how can I solve this problem? " phplover"

Comment: still not clear what you want since `23+20*2` does not equal `86` ... it's `63` but `(23+20)*2` does equal `86`

Comment: yes I know, and I do not know what is wrong

Comment: neither do we because you haven't provided proper information for what is needed

Comment: Yes I saw, she does not know the total from 23+20 to multiply to tow

Comment: the formula should be like: 23+20=43*2=86

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $('div#cont-sum-fields').on('change', 'input', function() {
        var total =  (parseInt($( "#cont-sum-1" ).val()) +  parseInt($( "#cont-sum-2" ).val())) * parseInt($( "#cont-sum-3" ).val()) ;

        $('#cont-sum-fields').find('#total-cont-sum').val(total);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id='cont-sum-fields'>
    (<input type="number" id="cont-sum-1" /> +
    <input type="number" id="cont-sum-2" />) x
    <input type="number" id="cont-sum-3" /> 
    <input id="total-cont-sum" type="number" disabled />
  </div>
```

Comment: you are the best tyyyyyyy

Comment: Id attribute is unique so `$('#total-cont-sum').val(total);`