# Calculations with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I found this script and its kind of what I need to learn right now.

[Similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840724/calculate-total-from-number-input-and-set-to-number-input)

I want to get some data from PHP and with that date to do the calculation!

But obviously i dont understand how to do it yet!

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $('div#cont-sum-fields').on('change', 'input', function() {
//        var total =  (parseInt($( "#cont-sum-1" ).val()) +  parseInt($( "#cont-sum-2" ).val())) * parseInt($( "#cont-sum-3" ).val()) ;
 var printsmall = 6;
//var pricesmall = <? echo $priceAUD[4][2];?>; // output 6.0
        var total =  (parseInt($( "#cont-sum-1" ).val()) +  parseInt($( "#cont-sum-2" ).val())) * pricesmall) ;
        $('#cont-sum-fields').find('#total-cont-sum').val(total);
        find('pricesmall').val(pricesmall);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id='cont-sum-fields'>
    (<input type="number" id="cont-sum-1" /> +
    <input type="number" id="cont-sum-2" />) x
    <input id="pricesmall" type="number" disabled /> =
    <input id="total-cont-sum" type="number" disabled />
  </div>
```

So a little summary of what I want to get done:

First number + Second number * php or the var printsmall = total!

Comment: You could populate the initial values of the HTML input elements via PHP

Comment: Since PHP is run on the server before any JS, you need to output the PHP variable in the JS source, so JS will use it as a "hard coded" value. Like: `var printsmall = <?= $the_php_variable; ?>;`, basically what you already have in line you have commented out.

Comment: The console says `Syntax error`, you have one extra `)` after `* pricesmall)`, the script crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code modified in the way I think you want it.

Please note the indentation etc, it makes reading code much easier.

```js
$(window).load(
  function(){
    var printsmall = 6;
    $('#pricesmall').val(printsmall);
    $('#cont-sum-fields').on('change', 'input', 
      function() {
        var 
          s1 = $('#cont-sum-1').val(),
          s2 = $('#cont-sum-2').val(); 
        if (s1 && s2) {
          $('#total-cont-sum').val(
            (parseFloat(s1) + parseFloat(s2)) * printsmall);
        }
      }
    )
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id='cont-sum-fields'>
    (<input type="number" id="cont-sum-1" /> +
    <input type="number" id="cont-sum-2" />) x
    <input id="pricesmall" type="number" disabled /> =
    <input id="total-cont-sum" type="number" disabled />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. im just learning!.. and i do think your code makes me understand it so i can get better at it!.. But lets see :) first day!